# Cordova install version disparity

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface

I ran this line of CLI code (on Mac OSX):

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

I even did this one:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.5.0-0.2.6
```

Then this one:

```
cordova --version
```

Expecting to see "3.5.0" or "3.5.0-0.2.6". No:

```
3.0.3
```

I need at least 3.1.0 for some plugins I need to use.

*What gives folks?*